Firebird-Postgres replication using Kafka
We have a bunch of sql queries running once a day to replicate data from Firebird to Postgres. I am working on moving this ETL process to Kafka. Some tables are large and requires immediate replication this is the reason why we considered such updates.
The simplest idea was to load data to Kafka using JDBC source connector from Firebird using timestamp column. Then use KSQL to transform data using old sql queries with aggregation/joins and upload this records to Postgres using JDBC sink connector. Foreing keys issue should be solved using DLQ and poll intervals.
The problem appears on JDBC source connectors creation. We have to load near 120 tables = 120 JDBC connectors. Each connectors creates 2 permanent connections to Firebird and this can be too much for database. Firebird doesn't have CDC tools therefore the only way to do that is to use JDBC driver with timestamp column. Is there any method to deal with such load? Is is possible to use connections pool for kafka connect server?
The other option is to use locally created logging system for Firebird used for changes detection. Each of create, update and delete event creates records on 2 tables:

SYS_REPLICATE (with timespamp, table name, action name (I for insert, U for update, D for delete) and upated/created/deleted row ID)
SYS_REPLICATE_S (containing column name, old value, new value and SYS_REPLICATE ID).

Using this 2 tables we can present action as sequence of columns updates.
For example, if we insert rows to table with 3 columns ID, col1, col2 we will have 1 record in SYS_REPLICATE with table name and 3 records in SYS_REPLICATE_S. I want to join SYS_REPLICATE with SYS_REPLICATE_S to get information about table name, column name and old|new values as sequence of updates. The idea was to group this events using KSQL but it seems impossible. I can filter this events by table name and run topic for each table. The problems begun when we have to map update in event to particular column. I cannot imagine how to do that. Can we group this events by table name and map colums by column name in the record?

Is using of Kafka a requirement? Much simpler (and faster) would be using firebird_fdw. BTW, timestamp-based approach has its gotchas so a newbie most likely will do it wrong and end up with missed records.

Yes it is a requirement. Thank you for information about firebird_fdw and timestamp-based approach. I will search more information about them. We are trying to apply timestamp based approach because it is the simplest way to catch updates in our tables.
